# How should I deal with non-normality in geostatistics?

Tags: normality-assumption, geostatistics, kriging

I am working with two parameters, one is normally distributed the other is not. I have read several different books and articles with different opinions on what to do with non-normal data. Since normality is a requirement of geostatistics, logarithmic and power (Box-Cox) transformations seem to be commonly used to achieve normality.  On the other hand I have also read that normality isn’t strictly required and is only needed for confidence intervals and probability maps. It seems to me that the best practice is to transform the data for the most efficient results, but in doing this I run into a couple of problems. Both parameters have significant trend, so in order to satisfy the stationarity requirement I must also detrend the data (following the trend removal method used by Vierra, 2010). The first problem: since one parameter is non-normal and has significant trend should I both transform and detrend the data before geostatistical analysis? Normality tests (histogram, q-q plots, shapiro wilks) on the residuals show that, ONLY detrending, improves normality but the data are still not normally distributed. Is it ok to perform geostatistical analysis on the residuals even though they are not normally distributed (I would prefer this option)? This brings me to my second problem: I want to be able to perform co-kriging using the two variables but I am not sure how to do this with one normal and one non-normal parameter. If I transform one parameter to achieve normality, how do I back transform the co-kriged predictions? If both variables needed transformation than a simple back transformation would work, I assume. I am not sure to what to do in the case of one normal and one non-normal parameter. I am really confused by this and would appreciate any advice. I would also appreciate any literature that addresses this.

Shapiro-Wilks results of raw data (positively skewed):
W = 0.9006, p-value = 3.393e-07

Shapiro-Wilks results of residuals (positively skewed):
W = 0.9195, p-value = 3.462e-06

Shapiro-Wilks results of transformed residuals using an inverse transformation (the simplest transformation which resulted in normality):
W = 0.9788, p-value = 0.06459

Vieira, Sidney Rosa, et al. "Detrending non stationary data for geostatistical applications." Bragantia 69 (2010): 01-08.